# Are there any method to forward a port from my physical machine to VPS?

Tags: linux, networking

[VPS port fowarding via SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/575088/how-to-use-my-vps-to-redirect-traffic-to-certain-port-tomy-windows-pc-which-is-b) Provides a method via SSH port forwarding, though, such method is quite unstable as when SSH connection disconnects, the forwarded port will be disconnected and reopened. Any alternatives?

I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04 hosted on AWS Lightsail.

Comment: After digging in a bit, SSH port exposure is actually the opposite from what I've described. It forwads a ssh server-side port to the ssh client-side port which in this case is essentially forwarding a VPS port onto my physical machine.